# How to set input alphanumeric value format in input field reactjs?

Tags: html, reactjs, user-input

I'm using reactjs in my project and want to set fixed format in input field that user can be enter only useful info. I already tried with react number format and try make custom but didn't get solution. so anybody help me for set format in input field like "ABCD-123EF".. means alphanumeric with dash and this is fix format. My code is:

```
<Input
      type="text"
      id="plate_number"
      name="plate_number"
      placeholder="Licence Plate"
      value={this.state.plate_number}
      onChange={this.onChangeHandle}
/>
```

[image]

Comment: You can look around this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-rxinput) which allows you to apply a regular expression on your input data.

Comment: @ⵍⵢⴻⵙ if possible then can you set format like above required?

Comment: You'll need to a regex like `^\w{4}-\w{4}$` or `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$` if you don't accept special characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use Regex to evaluate the incoming string like this.

```
onChangeAlphaNumericInput(e) {
  const value = e.target.value;
  const regex = /^[0-9a-zA-Z(\-)]+$/; //this will admit letters, numbers and dashes
  if (value.match(regex) || value === "") {
    this.setState({ inputValue: value });
  }
}
```

This will let your input to prevent to write any unwanted special character.

EDIT:

onBlur validation for that field

```
onBlurValidateFormat(e) {
  const value = e.target.value;
  const regex = /([a-zA-Z]{4})+-([0-9]{3})+([a-zA-Z]{2})+$/g;
  if (!value.match(regex)) {
    //Show an error message or put a warning text under the input and set flag to prevent form submit
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, in that case. I recomend to validate the format in an onBlur event. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

See my solution:

```
export const inputAlphaNumeric = (e, callback) => {

    const value = (e.target.value) ? e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]+/ig, "") : '';

    if (e.target.value !== value) {
        e.target.value = value;
    }

    if(typeof callback === 'function'){
        return callback(value);
    }
}
```

Add function in onChange input parameter:

```
<Form.Group>
    <Form.Label>Example</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control 
        type="text"
        defaultValue={""}
        onChange={(e) => inputAlphaNumeric(e, (value) => {
            // customize with your code
            this.setState({ custom: value  });
        })}
     />
</Form.Group>
```

Result:

[image]