# Material UI TextField Regex

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I need two textbox from TextField from MaterialUI one that can only enter alphabets(small or capital can also include spaces {Example : Risha Raj} as first textfield)
and other one is also except only alphabets (small or capital) but with maxLength with only 3

so I did the following

```
           <TextField
            id='Product Name'
            label='Enter Student  Name'
            name='sname'
            value={values.sname}
            onChange={handleChange}
            error={errors.sname}
          />
            <TextField
            id='section'
            label='Enter Class Section'
            name='ccode'
            inputProps={{maxLength:3}}
            value={values.ccode}
            onChange={handleChange}
            error={errors.ccode}
          />
```

I am able to restrict the length but unable to do the alphabets

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set input alphanumeric value format in input field reactjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61926968/how-to-set-input-alphanumeric-value-format-in-input-field-reactjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Material UI.

You need to create a validator function on your handleChange.

See: [How to set input alphanumeric value format in input field reactjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61926968/how-to-set-input-alphanumeric-value-format-in-input-field-reactjs)

Comment: Yes it would have but the problem come here is I am using Formick which is handling the handle change on onChange={handlEChange} so will it work in runtime without sending the data to formick and before only vaildating it with regex @Almaju

Comment: You can wrap the function from formik, there is no problem to do that.  Something like `onChange={(value) => handleChange(validate(value))}`